# Qt: multiple menus share the same actions but connect to different slots

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-signals, qt-slot

I have two menus with the same actions. But I would like to connect them to different slots depending on the menu. Can I do that?

The code below fails to do it, instead, it connects the actions to both slots.

I can create a different set of actions, with the same name. I am wondering whether there is a different way to do it without duplicating all the actions.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.menuBar)
        self.log = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.log)        

        fileMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('File')
        editMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('Edit')
        actions = []
        for i in range(5):
            action = QtWidgets.QAction('{}'.format(i), self)
            actions.append(action)
        fileMenu.addActions(actions)
        editMenu.addActions(actions)
        fileMenu.triggered.connect(self.file_action_triggered)
        editMenu.triggered.connect(self.edit_action_triggered)

    def file_action_triggered(self, action):
        print('File', action.text())
        self.log.append('File' + action.text())

    def edit_action_triggered(self, action):
        print('Edit', action.text())
        self.log.append('Edit' + action.text())


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When running the above code, and click "File - 1", I would expect only

```
File1
```

to be printed. Instead, it prints

```
File1
Edit1
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please explain.

Comment: You have not created QActions with similar names, which have assigned the same QActions to 2 QMenus. Beyond that problem you want to do?

Comment: i would love to know "whether there is a different way to do it without duplicating all the actions". I can definitely create another n actions which look exactly like the n actions I created previously. But since it is the menu who emits the signal (not the action itself), can I somehow let the slots know from which menu the signal is emmited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not created QActions with similar names, which have assigned the same QActions to 2 QMenus. What you should do is create 2 QActions with the same text and assign each one to a different QMenu.

For example:

```
for i in range(5):
    fileMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('{}'.format(i), self))
    editMenu.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction('{}'.format(i), self))
```

Comment: The objects that emit the signal are not the menus, they are the QActions, so it is impossible to do what you say.